# Google App Script to combine columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with multiple columns that have variable row counts in each column.  I would like to combine all the columns into one column.

So if the following is the data:
Column 1, column 2, Column 3, Column 4
Row 1: A, B, C, D
Row 2: ,,,E

I would want to get 
Row 1: A
Row 2: B
Row 3: C
Row 4: D
Row 5: E

I would like this to be non-destructive to the original sheet so it should create a new spreadsheet tab with a unique name. The unique name is important b/c i would like to run this function on multiple spreadsheets that are all different. The unique name will avoid overlap.

The request is to help me write the script to do this transpose in google apps spreadsheets

Thank you for the help!

Comment: so, what's the doubt? You just want someone to write a "transpose" script for you?

Comment: i have no idea how to write the script in google apps, so yes would be the answer to that. :)

Comment: not sure why the negative vote? doesn't seem very helpful or productive when someone asks for help and it gets voted down.

Comment: just read the tooltip description of the negative vote "This question does not show any research effort"... stackoverflow is a place for developers discussion, not for asking scripts/programs to developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the script, please let me know if you encounter any issues, at the moment it ignores blank cells and the value "0".

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet1.getLastColumn();
  var values = sheet1.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).getValues();
  var d = new Date();
  var newSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet("Sheet: "+d.getTime());
  var counter=1;
  for (var i=0;i<=lastRow-1;i++) {
    for (var j=0;j<=lastColumn-1;j++) {
      if(values[i][j]!="") {
        newSheet.getRange(counter,1).setValue(values[i][j]);
        counter++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try it out.  So it's basically javascript? By the way Andrei, are you on odesk or elance in case i need to post similar questions in the future?

Comment: since i wanted it all in one column, i ended up flipping these two lines:for (var i=0;i<=lastRow-1;i++) {
for (var j=0;j<=lastColumn-1;j++) { so that lastColumn comes before lastRow in the nesting.  alos, the variables in these two lines need to be flipped.

Comment: Andrei- I'm getting a caching issue.  If i run the same script on two different sheets, it only uses data from the first sheet.  I've tried it on two different computers and the same issue occurs.  I don't see anything in the script that should cause that.  Can you see if it caches for you too?  To replicate, (1) create to sheets with data across multiple rows and columns.  (2) run the script on the first sheet. (3) Run the script on the second sheet.  (4) see if the data is duplicated for both the new output sheets.

Comment: Hi Jignesh, if you want any sheet you're on to generate a new sheet with the data transposed, please replace this line: var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; with: sheet1 = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();